# How to show result of console.timeEnd() in react native android app?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have installed package and import it like this:

```
import 'react-native-console-time-polyfill';
```

and have function like this:

```
search = () => {
    let s = this.state.file.toLowerCase();
    let p = this.state.search.toLowerCase();
    console.time('t');
    let result = kmp.findAll(s, p);
    let time = console.timeEnd('t');
    alert(time);
};
```

Why the result in alert returned as "undefined"?

My expectation is result time for processing function is show up at alert popup. Search is a function onpress at button.

Sorry my bad english, hopefully you guys understand my question ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the library you are using is written, it only outputs the resulting time to console, it does not return it. Because of that, while you can see it in debug console, you will always receive `undefined` from both `.time()` and `.timeEnd()` functions. This is also the same for browsers, and you can actually test it in your Javascript console.

However the library's code seems to be short, you can actually add the functionality. If you add `return delta.toFixed(3);` at the end of the `.timeEnd()` function (21st line in the [index.js](http://%20https://github.com/MaxGraey/react-native-console-time-polyfill/blob/master/index.js)) you can get the result you want.